# Is it possible to add path segment after query parameter in OkHttp?

Tags: java, okhttp

I have an http url:

```
HttpUrl httpurl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
.scheme("https")
.host("www.example.com")
.addQueryParameter("parameter", "p")
.addPathSegment("extrasegment")
.build();
```

The query parameter always ends up last. How can I enforce the order that I want?

EDIT:

The reason I am trying to achieve this is because I want to be able to access certain endpoints that are formatted like so:

`https://host/api/{parameter}/anothersegment`

Comment: The URI specification sais that the query parameters always come after path segments. (See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) So the "query paramter" you are proposing is not actually a query parameter but rather part of the path segment. It would help if you could add an example of the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Would the desired result of the above code be `https://host/api/p/anothersegment` or `https://host/api/parameter=p/anothersegment` (then properly URL encoded)?

Comment: Thank you both for the input. Eventually, @JensV's answer helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume (from the original question) something like the following is desired:

```
https://www.example.com/?param=p/anothersegment
```

Taking the URI specification into account which defines this:

```
scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

The url would look something like this:

```
scheme = https
hier-part = www.example.com/
query = param=p/anothersegment
```

Which you can achieve like this:

```
HttpUrl httpurl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
.scheme("https")
.host("www.example.com")
.addEncodedQueryParameter("param", "p/anotersegment")
// Use `EncodedQueryParamter` to prevent escaping the slashes and other special characters. (You need to escape values yourself though)
.build();
```

---

From the edit though a guess might be that you want to achieve something like this:

```
https://www.example.com/foo=bar/baz=xy
```

Where the `foo=bar` and `baz=xy` are just more path segments which you can add with `addPathSegment`